How update the multiple data fetched from api and update submit to API
I am facing issues of submitting multiple records using the formadata
<div className="APDB_table-wrapper">
              <table className="table-Result">
                <tbody>
                  <tr className="table-Result-Row">
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">Application ID</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">Application Name</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">GSID</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">Sequence</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">Application DL</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">Manager DL</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">
                      Application Owner DL
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">DataCenter</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">QA SFTP ID</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">QA Password</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">PROD SFTP ID</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">PROD Password</th>
                    <th className="table-Result-Header">Updated User</th>
                  </tr>
                  {Result.map((item) => (
                    <tr key={item.acd_con_seq} className="table-Result-Data">
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="applicationId"
                          value={item.acd_ap_id}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="applicationName"
                          value={item.acd_ap_nm}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="gsid"
                          value={item.acd_ap_gsid}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Sequence"
                          value={item.acd_con_seq}
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="applicationDl"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_appl_dl = e.target.value;
                          }}
                          defaultValue={item.acd_appl_dl}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          name="leadManagerDl"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_lead_manager_dl}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_lead_manager_dl = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          name="systemOwnerNameDl"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_system_owner_name_dl}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_system_owner_name_dl = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="dataCenterName"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_dc_name}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_dc_name = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="qaSftpId"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_qa_sftp_id}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_qa_sftp_id = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="qaSftpPwd"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_qa_sftp_pwd}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_qa_sftp_pwd = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="prodSftpId"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_prod_sftp_id}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_prod_sftp_id = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="prodSftpPwd"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_prod_sftp_pwd}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_prod_sftp_pwd = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="updatedUser"
                          defaultValue={item.acd_upd_usr}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            item.acd_upd_usr = e.target.value;
                          }}
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" className="submit_Update" />
            </div>
          </Form>

result have api result as follows
acd_ap_gsid
: 
""
acd_ap_id
: 
""
acd_ap_nm
: 
""
acd_appl_dl
: 
""
acd_comments
: 
""
acd_con_seq
: 
"1"
acd_crt_date
: 
""
acd_crt_user
: 
""
acd_dc_name
: 
""
acd_lead_manager_dl
: 
""
acd_prod_sftp_id
: 
""
acd_prod_sftp_pwd
: 
""
acd_qa_sftp_id
: 
""
acd_qa_sftp_pwd
: 
""
acd_rg_nm
: 
""
acd_system_owner_name_dl
: 
""
acd_upd_date
: 
""
acd_upd_usr
: 
""

Data 2 
acd_ap_gsid
: 
""
acd_ap_id
: 
""
acd_ap_nm
: 
""
acd_appl_dl
: 
""
acd_comments
: 
""
acd_con_seq
: 
"2"
acd_crt_date
: 
""
acd_crt_user
: 
""
acd_dc_name
: 
""
acd_lead_manager_dl
: 
""
acd_prod_sftp_id
: 
""
acd_prod_sftp_pwd
: 
""
acd_qa_sftp_id
: 
""
acd_qa_sftp_pwd
: 
""
acd_rg_nm
: 
""
acd_system_owner_name_dl
: 
""
acd_upd_date
: 
""
acd_upd_usr
: 
""

The action I am calling
export async function action({ request }) {
  console.log(" functioncalled");
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(data)
  const newData=await updateAPDB(data);
  if (!newData === "1") {
    return null;
  } else {
    return redirect(`/webpage`);
  }
}


When I am trying access the formdata I am getting only sequence 2 data , I am unable to access the seq 1, I am not able to get the data of seq 1 to submit it into updatAPDB which calls api and update the data.

Are you able to clarify how updateAPDB works, I assume it just sends a single post request, but we should verify how it handles the post data. I think it's also important to detail how the action in DRF is setup to accept it. For example, is this one of it's normal POST/PATCH/PUT actions, or is this your own?
A very surface level comment, but it may help, if you are using DRF, and intending to update/create all objects at once. I'd suggest making a custom action, and post JSON data in the body.

I am using the POST as below:
try{
const res = await fetch (${API_URL}/updateAPDB,{
method:"POST",
body:JSON.stringify(updateAPDBData),
headers:{
"content-Type":"application/json"
},
});
if(!res.ok) throw Error();
const data=await res.json();
console.log('save return' + data)
return data;
}
catch{
throw Error ("Failed adding the Contact Details");
}

From the looks of it, the question you're asking may mislead readers, since you already are converting the formdata to JSON. I'd suggest verifying what JSON.stringify(updateAPDBData) produces, and also verifying what the API Endpoint accepts. If you're using Django REST Framework, it looks like a custom action, so perhaps the issue is in the backend?

Backend I am using DJango and for a single record I am able to update but not for multiple record.

try:     object=AppContactDetails.objects.get(acd_ap_id=acd_ap_id1,acd_con_seq=acd_seq1)
object.save(update_fields=['acd_lead_manager_dl','acd_system_owner_name_dl','acd_appl_dl','acd_system_owner_name_dl','acd_ap_gsid','acd_dc_name','acd_qa_sftp_id','acd_qa_sftp_pwd','acd_prod_sftp_id','acd_prod_sftp_pwd'])

Can you update your post with the Django code. The lines above don't make the issue clear. On the surface it looks like you're just updating 1 object, but is this within a loop?
If it is within a loop for each item you're updating, make sure you are getting the correct AppContactDetails object.

the thing is when I am clicking submit, even though it has two records displayed it is just taking record in formdata and the first record is being ignored.
